# Asp.net Core Webapi Azure CosmosDB update entity in different container

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi

I am completely new to using Azure CosmosDB SQL API. i am having a simple asp.net core webapi. I have two containers for Employer and Employee. The employee json data is as below:

```
{
  "id": "56b2aea8-df9e-41e8-a1d0-6ca77e625284",
  "name": "ABC",
  "employees": [
    {
      "id": "fd3e6a4b1af9xxxx",
      "name": "EMP1",
      "dateAdded": "02/09/2021 12:00:51"
    },
    {
      "id": "ecaa7250xxxx",
      "name": "EMP2",
      "dateAdded": "02/09/2021 13:29:29"
    }
  ]
}
```

And i want to create separate endpoint to Create/Edit employee. And the employee json data is:

```
{
    "dateOfBirth": "09/05/1976",
    "name": "EMP1Updated",
    "id": "80d9585a-1f6d-4348-b8e0-5d40f9586eb7",
}
```

I have separate repo for both Employer and Employee. If i change employee name, i have to change the corresponding employee name in Employer container. I am not sure how to achieve this. Can anyone suggest me the best solution to do this. The update code for employee is:

```
try
        {
            var container = _cc.GetContainer(_databaseId, _employeeDataContainerName);

            var sqlQueryText = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = @EmployeeId";
            var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText).WithParameter("@EmployeeId", id);
            var queryResultSetIterator =
                container.GetItemQueryIterator<EmployeeRecord>(queryDefinition);

            var currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();

            var firstRecord = currentResultSet.FirstOrDefault();
            if (firstRecord == default)
            {
                var message = $"Unable to find any employee for the given ID ({id})";
                throw new Exception(message);
            }
            var docToWrite = Mapper.MapToEmployeeRecord(employeeModel, learnerEntity.Id);
            await container.UpsertItemAsync(docToWrite, new PartitionKey(id.ToString()));
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data#what-about-foreign-keys

Answer (score 0):

The way to maintain referential integrity between two containers is to use change feed. Monitor one container using change feed, then when an item is updated you can call a function to query your employee container and call ReplaceItemAsync() on it. You can learn more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-design-patterns)